# possible to ssh with Ubuntu MATE

Tags: networking, wifi, ssh, ubuntu

I flashed the `Ubuntu MATE` distro with my `OSX`. Now I try to connect to my `pi` through `ssh`. I get an `IP` but when I try to log with ubuntu/ubuntu as a login/password, it does not work. Is it configured to support `ssh` ?

Comment: I Believe it is configured by default, what are you using for username and password? What is returned by this command ps aux | grep sshd?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I tried ubuntu:ubuntu

Comment: You need to use the username and password you created on first boot. copying from the Ubuntu mate Raspberry Pi page "NOTE! There are no predefined user accounts. The first time you boot the Ubuntu MATE image it will run through a setup wizard where you can create your own user account and configure your regional settings. The first boot is quite slow, but once the first boot configuration is complete subsequent boots are much quicker."

Comment: @SteveRobillard ok. I understand that my problem is perhaps heavier since I am trying to connect the pi to a screen via `HDMI` but nothing shows up. The power supply is good. The red led is on and the green started to blink irregularly but now it stopped. Do you have an idea of what it is going on ? Btw, I don't think it is a SD card problem since I have another pi wich I purchased and that I did not reformatted and I get the same issue

Answer (score 3):

First, I had to connect to the `pi` via display. At this step, I experienced interesting issue :  I couldn't have any image on the display. This was related to old screen/HDMI cable. I finally forced the config.txt file in that way : uncommenting hdmi_safe=1 and hdmi_force_unplug=1 and it did the trick.

Second, I realised that the problem that `ssh client` was indeed installed but `ssh server` was not. So I installed it and it did the trick !

Comment: I had to use `$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make a backup of the  original `ssh` configuration:

```
sudo cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.original
```

You can modify your SSH config at your own risk by editing the following file:

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Finally, you can run the following command to apply the changes:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Comment: Great answer, cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

You don't have SSH configured when system is first flashed. In fact, you can't properly set up the system unless you can connect it to a display. I haven't tried direct tty connection via USB, which may be possible.

My problem was with connecting to an old monitor via HDMI and not getting a picture. I connected to the TV and was able to complete the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Old Post but :

Flash Mate to microsd and make a file called ssh (without .txt extension) in the Boot partition. Boot PI. Connect with Putty over ssh to your PI´s IP Adress username "pi" Password "raspberry"

See also.
https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/

Answer (score -3):

this works:

ssh UbuntuMateUserName@192.168.0.19

password prompt: UbuntuMatePassword

Comment: Did you read the other answers the OP answered his own question. The problem was the SSH server was not running.